# Not able to get JSON response using CURL PHP

Tags: php, json, curl, server

I am trying to write a PHP script that post username and password as JSON object to a server and in response get a JSON object that contains UserId and token in JSON.

Following is my code

```
if (isset($_GET["user"]) && isset($_GET["key"])){

$username = $_GET["user"];
$pass = $_GET["key"];

$data = array("username" => $username, "password" => $pass);                                                                                   
$data_string = json_encode($data);              
echo $data_string;

$ch = curl_init('https://sce15.appspot.com/api/g_usrs/signin');                                                                                                                                           
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));                                                                                                                   

$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

$usr = json_decode($response, true);
echo $usr;

}
else{

    echo "Oops Something went wrong: Error 1";
}
```

But I am not getting anything in output, my browser window is white blank. I am not able to figure out the mistake. I am able to get JSON object when using javascript for the same URL, but I need to do it with PHP.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: This is going to be impossible to answer without knowing the web service you're posting to, and how it responds.

Comment: the webserver gives me the JSON object with some values. The problem is not with server, i have tested the same using javascript script

Comment: Maybe the JSON is bad?

Comment: JSON is perfectly formed, i have tested it, Do you think that the code is error free ?

Comment: you have a totally blank screen? so even `echo $data_string;` doesn't print anything?

Comment: @BeetleJuice echo $data_string is  printing the JSON object

Comment: Ok. So what exactly do you mean when you write "my browser window is white blank."?  Have you already tried making the cURL request to some endpoint whose inputs you can read? so that you will see exactly what cURL is sending?

Comment: @BeetleJuice I meant that its a white blank page, if i am echoing the paramenters or JSON object that i am sending it successfully appear on page but, if i try to echo result of CURL post it does not echo anything and also give no errors, Do you think there can be a mistake in the way  i am trying to echo result ?

Comment: If `json_decode` fails, it will return `NULL` and nothing will be echoed to the page.  Instead, try to echo the raw response with `echo $response`

Comment: @BeetleJuice I tried but it is also not echoing something

Answer (score 1):

I finally pointed out the problem after 2 days of head banging on google. It was the SSL certificate error, CURL was not able to verify the SSL certificate.

I got to knew that after checking curl errors `print_r(curl_error($ch));`

And then by using the `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);` i was able to disable SSL certificate security check. Although it made my connection insecure but i think that's not important in my case.

Thanks Everyone